# Findig max value for multiple columns and deleting the rest from there, code not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have long sets of data with multiple columns, and the idea is to for each column, find the maximum value, delete the rest of the data after that maximum value, and keep the data before the max. I found an old code that claims to do exactly what I want but when I copy it/transcribe it as a macro, it simply doesn't compile.  I keep getting "compile error, expected: name parameter" from the 5th row onwards. here is the code, in case anyone with a much better understanding of vba than me can try and figure out the problem, otherwise, propose a solution for my dilemma.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

working code:

```
Sub deleteaftermax()
Dim I As Integer
For I = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    If WorksheetFunction.Count(Columns(i)) > 0 Then
        Range(Columns(i).Find(What:=WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns(i)), _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(3), _
            Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp)).Clear
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

EDIT: the problem was easily solved by adding an underscore on line 5, thanks again for pointing this out! I will leave the code (fixed) in case anyone needs a similar approach.

Comment: Welcome to so, did you try adding an underscore after `WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns(i)),`?

Comment: yeah, apparently that was the problem, a missing underscore for continuity! thanks for the help!